# Proof: Continuity in $\mathbb R$ implies continuity in $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: proof-verification, continuity

I am trying to prove this statement about continuity on the reals:]

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be continuous using the Euclidean distance function. Then the function $g:\mathbb R^n \to\mathbb R^n$ defined by
>   $$g(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=(f(x_1),f(x_2),...,f(x_n))$$
>   is continuous in Euclidean $n$-space.

Here is my proof:

Since $f$ is continuous, for any given value of $\epsilon\gt 0$, there exists $\delta\gt 0$ such that
$$|a-b|\lt \delta\implies|f(a)-f(b)|\lt \epsilon$$
I will use $\delta[\epsilon]$ to represent such a value of $\delta$.

Now suppose that $\epsilon'\gt 0$ is given. Let
$$\delta'=\delta\bigg[\frac{\epsilon'}{\sqrt n}\bigg]$$
Then suppose we have that
$$\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n (a_k-b_k)^2}\lt \delta'$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n (a_k-b_k)^2\lt \delta'^2$$
and, for each $k$,
$$(a_k-b_k)^2\lt \delta'^2$$
$$|a_k-b_k|\lt \delta'$$
$$|a_k-b_k|\lt \delta\bigg[\frac{\epsilon'}{\sqrt n}\bigg]$$
and, by the way we defined $\delta[\epsilon']$, this implies
$$|f(a_k)-f(b_k)|\lt \frac{\epsilon'}{\sqrt n}$$
$$n(f(a_k)-f(b_k))^2\lt \epsilon'^2$$
$$(f(a_k)-f(b_k))^2+(f(a_k)-f(b_k))^2+...+(f(a_k)-f(b_k))^2\lt \epsilon'^2$$
where the LHS of the above statement contains $n$ copies of $(f(a_k)-f(b_k))^2$. Since this is true for all $k$, even the $k$ for which $(f(a_k)-f(b_k))^2$ is maximized, we have that
$$(f(a_1)-f(b_1))^2+(f(a_2)-f(b_2))^2+...+(f(a_n)-f(b_n))^2\lt \epsilon'^2$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n (f(a_k)-f(b_k))^2\lt \epsilon'^2$$
$$\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n (f(a_k)-f(b_k))^2}\lt \epsilon'$$
Which completes the proof.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Correct. However, the remark about $(f(a_k) - f(b_k))^2$ maximization is unnecessary, just add up the inequalities $(f(a_k)-f(b_k))^2 < \epsilon'^2/n$ for $k=1, 2, \ldots, n$.

Comment: Your $k$'s turned into $n$'s at the end,

Comment: @Adayah Okay, thanks!

Comment: @zhw Whoops, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other users basically already answered your question, I just want to recommend that you try showing this by proving that the preimage of any open set is open. This would save you a lot of time.  You could also prove this by taking the limits and showing they exist. Both of these are much shorter.

Comment: Ah, good idea. Thanks!